# Using python's mock patch to test class doesn't works

Tags: python, unit-testing, mocking, patch

I am having hard times with unittest mock and patch. I'd like to test a specific class and change some attributes in it.

I think that I have a path problem but can't figure how to resolve it.

```
#lib.inventory.py
class Inventory(object):

    def __init__(self):
        self.db = "12"

    def do_stuff(self):
        return "ok"

#test.py
import unittest
from mock import patch
import time
from  lib.inventory import Inventory

#test_case.py
class MyTest(unittest.TestCase):
    @patch('lib.inventory.Inventory')  
    def test_retrieve_project_id(self,mock_inventory):

        print "####################"
        print Inventory
        print mock_inventory
        print "####################"
```

When I run this test I should see that both `Inventory` and `mock_inventory` objects points to the same MagickMock Object. But it isn't the case :

```
####################
<class 'lib.inventory.Inventory'>
<MagicMock name='Inventory' id='140594977874320'>
####################
```

Could you tell me what I am doing wrong ?? Maybe I have misanderstood mock and patch concept ?
Thank you

Comment: Please correct grammar errors such as `i` instead of `I`, extra spaces and use  the characters \` \` for embed code in your text.

Comment: `import lib` and then `print lib.inventory.Inventory`. By importing the name directly with `from` you can't qualify it for `patch`.

Comment: You have to see how you are referring to the name where you use it, and patch that "path".

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow :)